# Angular2: Detect form changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

In Angular2 4.0 I have a `FormGroup` looking like this:

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
      a: ['', [Validators.required]],
      b: ['', [Validators.required]],
      c: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
```

Is it possible to subscribe `valueChanged` on individual fields?

I dont want to detect changes on input `c`, so the below approach does not work:

```
this.form.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).subscribe(data => {
     // Do something
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add separate subscriptions for FormControl **a** and **b**.

```
this.heroForm.controls["a"].valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
 // Do something
});

this.heroForm.controls["b"].valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
 // Do something
});
```

Comment: how can I monitor on the entire form?

Answer (score 4):

```js
  
//get form ref  
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm;

//implement afterview init to your class and use
// or you can use same code with ngOnInit

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.myForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe(data =>            console.log('Form changes', data));
}
```

> You can use this code, it will give you changed field data also.

Comment: Don't forget to implement `afterViewInit`

Answer (score 0):

```
          this.form.valueChanges
            .pipe(
              debounceTime(500), // Wait for 0.5
              distinctUntilChanged() //  execute only if a different value is emitted
            )
            .subscribe((newForm) => {
              console.log(newForm);
            });
```